# Parts of Brain Active for Dreams | Right Hemisphere or Cortex

Tags: neuroscience, brain, sleep

I found a research that states [cortex](https://www.sciencefocus.com/the-human-body/what-happens-when-we-dream/#:%7E:text=The%20whole%20brain%20is%20active,the%20thalamus%20to%20the%20cortex.) is responsible for the contents of the dream. Contents could be people, place, objects etc.

> The cortex is responsible for the content of dreams, including the monsters we flee from, the people we meet, or the experience of flying. Since we are highly visual animals the visual cortex, right at the back of the brain, is especially active, but so are many other parts of the cortex.

While the other says [right hemisphere](https://corrosion-doctors.org/Dreaming%20is%20Personal/Brain.htm#:%7E:text=The%20right%20hemisphere%20of%20the,in%20that%20hemisphere%20during%20REM.) is responsible  to create the dream.

> The right hemisphere of the brain actually creates and displays the dream

And another [source](http://brainmind.com/Dreaming.html#:%7E:text=Based%20on%20an%20extensive%20review,contents%20have%20their%20source%20in)

> the dream contents have their source in memories and impressions stored within the right half of the brain.

While there is another research that states [posterior cortical hot zone](https://www.sciencealert.com/scientists-have-found-the-brain-s-hot-zone-that-shows-when-we-re-dreaming) that are responsible for our dreams.

**Question:** So what part of the brain is it? I know a coordination of various parts of the brain makes dreams possible but what part of the brain is responsible for main contents of the dream or major contributor to the dream?

Comment: Search this on google scholar- you will get a well sourced answer. Three of your sources are unreliable.